# Convert normal array into an object array in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have the below list of array:

```
var number = [];
var counter = [];
var time = [];

number[0] = "1212";
counter[0] = "2";
time[0] = "12:30PM";

number[1] = "9367";
counter[1] = "4";
time[1] = "05:30PM";

number[2] = "4786";
counter[2] = "8";
time[2] = "09:30AM";
```

How do I convert the above into an object array like below:

```
var abc = [
{number: "1212", counter: "2", time: "12:30PM"},
{number: "9367", counter: "4", time: "05:30PM"},
{number: "4786", counter: "8", time: "09:30AM"}
];
```

So far, I've tried to use below coding to convert but failed:

```
var abc=[];
abc[0].number = "1212";
abc[0].counter = "2";
abc[0].time = "12:30PM";
```

Do you guys know how?

Comment: Why don't you create the desired structure in the first place? Initialize objects and push them into an array.

Comment: How do we initialize?

Comment: This article covers it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `abc[0]` as an object then updates it's property.

```js
var abc = [];
abc[0] = {};
abc[0].number = "1212";
abc[0].counter = "2";
abc[0].time = "12:30PM";

console.log(abc);
```

or initialize it with all object property.

```js
var abc = [];
abc[0] = {
  number: "1212",
  counter: "2",
  time: "12:30PM"
}

console.log(abc);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number.map(function(num,index) {
return {
number: number[index],
counter: counter[index],
time: time[index]
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your `number,counter, time` array is like this.

You can use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array method to loop through each of the object and fill the **abc** array, `item & index` are parameters which are accepted by forEach function

```
    var number = ["1212","9367","4786"];
    var counter = ["2","4","8"];
    var time = ["12:30PM","05:30PM","09:30AM"];

    var abc =[];

    number.forEach(function(item,index){
    abc.push({
      name:number[index],
      counter:counter[index],
      time:time[index]
    })
    })

console.log(abc)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/f15oyngd/)